# Regex pattern isn't matching in python but works in regex101

Tags: python, regex

Given text that looks like this:

```
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
100.32.205.59 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
```

For each line I want to match the IP, username, timestamp and request type/path. Trying to use this pattern:

`([0-9\.]+)[- ]+([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\s\[([0-9]{2}\/[A-Za-z]+\/[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} -[0-9]{4})\] \"[A-Z]+ [A-Za-z0-9\/\- \.+]+\"`

When I test this on regex101.com it works just fine, but using `re.findall()` gives me 0 matches. The problem seems to be at `-[0-9]{4}`(about 3/4ths the way through the string, meant to match -0700). If I remove everything starting with the hyphen character, it starts finding matches. Why would python have an issue with this?

Comment: Step 1: use a regex debugger and put in both your regex, and your data, and see what it does, with the description of your pattern to verify you wrote what you thought you did. If you're using regex101, did you pick the correct regex engine? And if you did, can you show your code? (literally copy-pasted, of course, instead of assembled of what's already in your post, because typos abound, and it's entirely possible that what your code has, and what you've put in your post here, subtly differ).

Comment: I have Python selected on regex101 and it works fine. The pattern string and test string are copied directly, there shouldn't be any issues with typos or anything

Comment: It works fine in python too, so you're going to have to show a [mcve] of this. When I run your regex against that data, I get `[('146.204.224.152', 'feest6811', '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700'), ('197.109.77.178', 'kertzmann3129', '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700'), ('156.127.178.177', 'okuneva5222', '21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700'), ('100.32.205.59', 'ortiz8891', '21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700')]`

Comment: Please include your code.  especially since it does work in regex 101, it's clear the problem is not the regex exactly. maybe quoting or escaping or something else in the code

Comment: Must have added the code

Answer (score 0):

I had the re.VERBOSE flag on and it turns out that was the culprit, I removed it and it works fine.

Comment: `([0-9.]+)[- ]+([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\s\[([0-9]{2}/[A-Za-z]+/[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s-[0-9]{4})\]\s\"[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9 +\--/]+\"`

https://regex101.com/r/IqmyPF/1

Be aware you're using way too much specific detail  in the group 3 date section. Also, anywhere you expect a space, make it optional and variable `\s*`